# Grails 2.2.4 unresolved dependencies commons-imaging

Tags: apache, grails, grails-2.2

So I'm kinda lost here.

I've had the same `BuildConfig` for over a month, and since the beginning of the week I have the following problem:

I'm trying to use the [Apache commons-imaging 1.0-SNAPSHOT](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) in my `grails 2.2.4` project using the following configuration:

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
repositories{
...
mavenRepo 'http://repository.apache.org/snapshots'
...
}

dependencies{
...
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
...
}
```

But every now and then, after running the `grails clean` command (I've tried from the terminal and from `GGTS`), I get an `unresolved dependencies` error.

At the very moment I write this question, the `run-app` command just worked although it failed every time for the last hour, giving the following error:

```
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /data/Documents/projectPath/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/elasticsearch-0.0.3.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/quartz-1.0.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/webflow-2.0.8.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/asual-lesscss-resources-0.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/browser-detection-0.4.3/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/aws-sdk-1.7.7/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/mail-1.0.5/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/jars/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/bundles/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/src/libs/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/src/libs/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/dist/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/dist/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-commons-imaging/tags/RELEASE_1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-commons-imaging/tags/RELEASE_1.0-SNAPSHOT/grails-commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== http://repo.spring.io/milestone: tried
      http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== http://repository.apache.org/snapshots: tried
      http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:::: ERRORS
    SERVER ERROR: Proxy Error url=http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /data/Documents/projectPath/project/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/elasticsearch-0.0.3.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/quartz-1.0.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/webflow-2.0.8.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/asual-lesscss-resources-0.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/browser-detection-0.4.3/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/aws-sdk-1.7.7/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/mail-1.0.5/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/jars/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/bundles/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/src/libs/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/src/libs/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/dist/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/dist/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-commons-imaging/tags/RELEASE_1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-commons-imaging/tags/RELEASE_1.0-SNAPSHOT/grails-commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== http://repo.spring.io/milestone: tried
      http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== http://repository.apache.org/snapshots: tried
      http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /data/Documents/projectPath/project/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/elasticsearch-0.0.3.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/quartz-1.0.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/webflow-2.0.8.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/asual-lesscss-resources-0.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/browser-detection-0.4.3/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/aws-sdk-1.7.7/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/projects/project/plugins/mail-1.0.5/lib/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/ivy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/jars/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/lib/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/bundles/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/src/libs/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/src/libs/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/dist/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/dist/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.gvm/grails/current/plugins/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-commons-imaging/tags/RELEASE_1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-commons-imaging/tags/RELEASE_1.0-SNAPSHOT/grails-commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      /home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== http://repo.spring.io/milestone: tried
      http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ==== http://repository.apache.org/snapshots: tried
      http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
      -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT!commons-imaging.jar:
      http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.apache.commons#commons-imaging;1.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

This isn't really preventing me from developing as it works *most* of the time, but it is really annoying because I keep wasting time trying to figure out why it happens.

**Does anybody here know why this happens? Is my config wrong?**

**P.-S.** I don't know if this might have any impact on the error, but here are a couple more informations:

1. my `grails` is configured using `gvm` (I have two versions installed, `2.2.4` (default) and `2.4.2`). I have also tried - to no avail - using a manual install and deleting all the corresponding `gvm` files in `~/.gvm` using both `gvm rm grails 2.2.4` and `gvm rm grails 2.4.2`.
2. I'm using this `jdk`: `java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.3.fc20.x86_64` and my `JAVA_HOME`, `GRAILS_HOME` and `PATH` are correctly set.
3. I realised that `grails` isn't looking for the `jar` in `~/.grails/ivy-cache/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/jars` although it is there but in `~/.grails/2.2.4/` where it isn't.

As I said, I'm lost. Any help understanding what is happening would be great!

Thanks

**P.-S. (again)** reading the log, it seems I have a proxy problem. I'm certain I did not change my settings. Did I just get trolled by the Apache website and spend an hour looking for a bug that does not exist within my code?

Comment: It seems the repository is down again. Does nobody out there have information regarding its status?