# Apache repository down?

Tags: java, gradle, apache-commons-cli

I am trying to build a program in java which uses Apache Commons CLI and I have gotten this error - it was working well until now. Does it mean Apache repository is down? If so, what is the best way to resolve this issue?

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
>
> > Could not resolve commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3-SNAPSHOT.
> >               Required by:
> >                   :dpg-variant-store:0.1
> >     Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
> >     Could not GET 'https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
> >     Received status code 503 from server: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: anything with "-SNAPSHOT" in it is not yet final and it subject to change and can break your application if it does change; so you should avoid putting in such versions yourself or using libraries which themselves depend on such things. looks like you might be using gradle (you should always put the commands/tools into any such report) so you should get gradle to dump your dependencies with `gradle dependencies` and try to fix the versions you are using. also look at removing any repos which are not 'main stream' in your build config.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431856/grails-2-2-4-unresolved-dependencies-commons-imaging) earlier today. I have been using the commons-imaging snapshot for a while and it only started failing to download recently. Does anybody know what's up with Apache's repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@simbo1905 is correct. It may be possible that snapshot library may have been edited or renamed.
You must use a finalized library. You can use this URL for obtaining finalized library
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/commons-cli/commons-cli/

You may have to edit your repository URL to read from this as Apache repository is only having a snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, how can I know when 1.3 will be released?

Comment: You need to keep looking at public repositories. Like mvnrepository.com; or on https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

Comment: Is there any other way to know when that release is scheduled other than checking the list everyday?

Comment: I am not aware of that. Sorry.

Comment: the commons-cli is on git hub. https://github.com/apache/commons-cli in case you are github member, then if you select 'Watch' on this page, you will keep getting notifications as to when the 1.3 is released.